# Loading More than 1 CSV File at a Time

Tags: vba, csv, excel, file-import

How does one import CSV files via Excel VBA in a set, in groups or in multiple individual files, rather than one at a time?

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit puzzled in that most versions of Excel will open .csv files with out any problems.

```
strPath = "C:\Docs\"
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")

Do While strFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=strPath & strFile
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strPath & Mid(strFile, 1, InStr(strFile, ".") - 1) _
        & "Conv.xls", FileFormat:=xlNormal

    strFile = Dir
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get a file into a one dimensional array quickly

```
Open "myfile.csv" For Input As 1
Dim Txt As String
Txt = Input(LOF(1), 1)
Close #1
Dim V As Variant
V = Split(Txt, ",")
```

Then V contains all the items in a single column, NB first item is V(0)

Comment: I think you'd be better off splitting on vbNewLine to break the file up into lines, and then splitting each line on comma. That way you'd be able to address each field as V(line)(column). line and column would be zero-based of course.

Comment: Also, this assumes the fields aren't quote delimited or contain embedded commas.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way that avoids the recalc you get when opening a csv file in Excel.

Add a blank sheet to your workbook and add the following code the sheet's object

```
Function getCsv(fn)
    Dim d, scrup As Boolean
    scrup = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Me.QueryTables.Add( _
            Connection:="TEXT;" & fn, _
            Destination:=Me.Range("A1") _
        )
        .Name = "data"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    d = Me.Names(1).RefersToRange.Value

    Me.Names(1).Delete
    Me.UsedRange.Rows.Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = scrup
    getCsv = d
End Function
```

You might also want to hide the sheet, so that no one accidentally uses it.
Then you can use like this

```
dim d
d = getCsv("C:\temp\some.csv")
```

One thing that slightly concerns me is that the Name gets incremented each time you use the function (e.g. data_1, data_2, ...), so there might be a stability issue if these names get saved somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple console application to parse a batch of csv files and save them to excel files.
Not the easiest solution but it could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use workbooks.opentext

Answer (score 0):

The idea I had originally was as follows. Given this data

```
Dog Names,Dog Ages,Collar Size
Woof,3,4
Bowser,2,5
Ruffy,4.5,6
Angel,1,7
Demon,7,8
Dog,9,2
```

create three global arrays, called `Dog_Names`, `Dog_Ages` and `Collar_Size` and populate them with the data in the CSV file.

This bit of VBScript does that job and displays the results. Remove the comment mark from the `wscript.echo` in the `x` subroutine to see it all happen.

```
Option Explicit

Dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )

Dim oStream
Dim sData
Dim aData

Set oStream = fso.OpenTextFile("data.csv")
sData       = oStream.ReadAll
aData       = Split( sData, vbNewLine )

Dim sLine
sLine = aData(0)

Dim aContent
aContent = Split( sLine, "," )

Dim aNames()
Dim nArrayCount
nArrayCount = UBound( aContent )
ReDim aNames( nArrayCount )

Dim i

For i = 0 To nArrayCount
  aNames(i) = Replace( aContent( i ), " ", "_" )
  x "dim " & aNames(i) & "()"
Next

For j = 0 To nArrayCount
  x "redim " & aNames(j) & "( " & UBound( aData ) - 1 & " )"
Next

Dim j
Dim actual
actual = 0

For i = 1 To UBound( aData )
  sLine = aData( i )
  If sLine <> vbnullstring Then
    actual = actual + 1
    aContent = Split( sLine, "," )
    For j = 0 To nArrayCount
      x aNames(j) & "(" & i - 1 & ")=" & Chr(34) & aContent(j) & Chr(34)
    Next
  End If
Next

For j = 0 To nArrayCount
  x "redim preserve " & aNames(j) & "(" & actual - 1 & ")"
Next

For i = 0 To actual - 1
  For j = 0 To nArrayCount
    x "wscript.echo aNames(" & j & ")," & aNames(j) & "(" & i & ")"
  Next
Next

Sub x( s )
  'wscript.echo s
  executeglobal s
End Sub
```

The result looks like this

```
>cscript "C:\Documents and Settings\Bruce\Desktop\datathing.vbs"
Dog_Names Woof
Dog_Ages 3
Collar_Size 4
Dog_Names Bowser
Dog_Ages 2
Collar_Size 5
Dog_Names Ruffy
Dog_Ages 4.5
Collar_Size 6
Dog_Names Angel
Dog_Ages 1
Collar_Size 7
Dog_Names Demon
Dog_Ages 7
Collar_Size 8
Dog_Names Dog
Dog_Ages 9
Collar_Size 2
>Exit code: 0    Time: 0.338
```

Comment: boost - as I understand it ExecuteGlobal (and Execute) are only available in VBScript but not in VBA?